# How to add JButton mouse position?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

**UPDATE:**

I fixed it with mouseEnter and mouseExit. I added a mouse adapter and a mouse listener to fix it. I made it so that when the mouse is entered it is red and when it leaves it is black. Will this still work if I make the button invisible and make my own custom button? Will I still be able to keep the play text?

**My code:**

```
package Main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class Game extends JPanel {
public Game() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tennis Game");

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(null);

    final JButton b = new JButton("Play");

    b.setBackground(new Color(220,220,220));
    b.setFocusPainted(false);
    b.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 20));
    b.setBounds(110, 100, 80, 40);
    b.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

    b.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter(){

        public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            b.setForeground(Color.RED);
        }

        public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            b.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        }

    });

    frame.add(b);
    frame.setSize(300,400);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}



public static void main(String[] args) {
     SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             new Game();
         }
     });
 }

 }
```

**Thanks!!**

Comment: This is easy to do if you use images for the 'text' instead of actual text.  `JButton` supports all different types of icons, standard, roll over, focused, pressed..  Set appropriate icons for each and button will do the rest.

Comment: Can you give an example, I'm kind of confused.

Comment: Oh, and `new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20)` should be `new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 20)` to accommodate those desktop machines that have a superior non-decorated font (like OS X with Helvetica).

Comment: *"I'm kind of confused."* What are you confused about?  Be specific (and show an attempt).

Answer (score 3):

1. You will need to use the `mouseEnter` and `mouseExit` events from `MouseListener`;
2. You shouldn't and you will have no end of issues if your try; the Swing API is designed around the use layout managers, an attempt to do without them, will result in you reinventing the wheel with hacks to over come all the issues you run into
3. You will have disable the current border painting (`setBorderPainted`) and then apply your own border, something like `LineBorder`

Start by taking a look at [How to use Mouse Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) and [How to us Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more details...

> Using mouseEnter I tried it but when I do it It doesn't work.

First, read the tutorial [How to use Mouse Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            JButton btn = new JButton("play");
            add(btn);

            btn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                    btn.setText(btn.getText().toUpperCase());
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                    btn.setText(btn.getText().toLowerCase());
                }

            });
        }

    }

}
```

But I agree with AndrewThompson, you'd be better of using a "normal" icon and a "roll over" icon...

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            JButton btn = new JButton();
            add(btn);

            try {
                btn.setIcon(new ImageIcon(
                                ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Play-Plain.png"))
                ));
                btn.setRolloverIcon(new ImageIcon(
                                ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Play-RollOver.png"))
                ));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Using mouseEnter I tried it but when I do it It doesn't work. It gives me b.mouseEnter(evt,x,y). What is evt and how to I make the event to where it changes color?

Comment: You add the MouseListener to the button itself?

Comment: Yes, I imported mouseListener and used the mouse enter for the button

Comment: Update your question to include what you have tried